# Jquery prevent hiding elements on hover. clearTimeout on hover, setTimeout on mousemove

Tags: jquery, settimeout, mousemove

I'm trying to achive sidebar and two navigation buttons were hiding with delay when mouse cursor stop moving. When mouse cursor moves again elements should appear. Code works fine but...
how to prevent hiding three elements when they are in hover state.

Where should I add clearTimeout on hover state? Should I? Sory I'm beginner in jQuery.

Here is my code:

html:

```
<div class="container">
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="prev">prev</div>
<div class="next">next</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container { position: absolute; left: 20px; top: 2px; right:2px; bottom: 20px; border: 1px solid red; }
nav { position: absolute; left: 0; top:0; bottom: 0; border: 1px solid blue; }
.prev { position: absolute; width: 50px; height: 30px; bottom: 0; left: 45%; border: 1px solid green; }
.next { position: absolute; width: 50px; height: 30px; top: 0; left: 45%; border: 1px solid green; }
```

JS

```
var timeout = false;
var count = $(function() {
$('.container').mousemove(function(e) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('hide slideshow elements');
        $('.container nav').fadeOut();
        $('.prev').fadeOut();
        $('.next').fadeOut();
    }, 2500);            
});
});

$(".container").mousemove(function() {
console.log('show slideshow elements');
$('.container nav').fadeIn();
$('.prev').fadeIn();
$('.next').fadeIn();
});
```

And JSfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/h3wDt/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add a `hover` variable to store whether it is over nav, it may not be the best way, but it work

http://jsfiddle.net/h3wDt/5/

Comment: Wow! I thought it will be more complicated. Thanks for your help. Greetings!

Answer (score 2):

I checked the event targets tagname to see if it was an anchor tag. seems to have worked as well.

```
var timeout = false;
var count = $(function() {
    $('.container').mousemove(function(e) {
        $('.container nav').fadeIn();
        $('.prev').fadeIn();
        $('.next').fadeIn();
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        if (e.target.tagName != "A") {
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                console.log('hide slideshow elements');
                $('.container nav').fadeOut();
                $('.prev').fadeOut();
                $('.next').fadeOut();
            }, 2500);            
        }
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DDMqM/3/)

Comment: I like this answer as it approaches the exact issue with the problem.